# Retrieving certain rows from a table through ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, haml

I am *very* new to Ruby on Rails, and come from a C++ background, so some of this stuff is somewhat confusing. Please bear with me if this question sounds retarded, but I'm stumped.

Say I've a class called Bet:

```
class Bet < ActiveRecord::Base
```

The bets table is as follows:

```
  create_table "bets", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "text"
    t.boolean  "completed",       :default => false
    t.boolean  "won_by_bettor"
    t.integer  "bet_against"
    t.datetime "twitter_tstamp"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "tweet_id"
  end
```

I'm trying to retrieve and display certain bets (based on, say, user_id) in a .haml file. How could I go about doing this?

If I try something like this in my .haml file:

> #{Bet.find(:all)}

I get something that looks like this:

```
#<Bet:0x2aaefc6c3920>#<Bet:0x2aaefc6be0b0>#<Bet:0x2aaefc6bdfc0>#<Bet:0x2aaefc6bdf20>#<Bet:0x2aaefc6bde80>#<Bet:0x2aaefc6bdde0>#<Bet:0x2aaefc6bdd40>#<Bet:0x2aaefc6bdca0>#<Bet:0x2aaefc6bdc00>#<Bet:0x2aaefc6bd368>#<Bet:0x2aaefc6bd278>#<Bet:0x2aaefc6bd1d8>#<Bet:0x2aaefc6bd0e8>#<Bet:0x2aaefc6bd048>#<Bet:0x2aaefc6bcfa8>
```

Which is obviously not what I want displayed.

Any help would be really appreciated.

**EDIT (based on nathanvda's answers/suggestions)**

I'll clarify what I want to do exactly: I am able to display all the bets made *by* the user against someone else; however, I am also trying to display bets made by someone else *against* the user. This is where I am hitting a roadblock.

My logic is to check the bets table where the "bettee"=user (for lack of a better word, the user against whom the bet is made), and then display those bets. Thus, I would ideally like my show method to display all the bets made AGAINST (not by - since this is already working) the user.

I have a simple question: does the method NEED to be called "show"? Or should it be called "index"? Or does the name matter, based on the view it corresponds to? I've currently implemented the method as "show" but I'm still getting an error, which for some reason, makes me think that the view (show.html.haml) is not able to "interface" (again, for lack of a better word) with bet_controller.rb. In the last 2 lines of the view (lines 68 and 69, which I commented out - [pastebin.com/rJWMntL0](http://pastebin.com/rJWMntL0) ), when I use exactly what dmarkow had suggested, I get an error ("We're sorry, but something went wrong.").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your comments i can see it is still very new. Rails is MVC, in short it means that the C=Controller collects all data.

Did you use scaffolding to create your `bets_controller.rb`? I guess not, you should try in the command-line in the root-folder of your application. Do something like

```
rails g scaffold Bet  text:string completed:boolean won_by_bettor:boolean ...
```

and add all your fields. This will create the model, the migration, the controller and sample views.
When getting started this is a great way to see how everything ties together.

What you then would see that inside the controller all data is retrieved (the models), and the view does only the rendering. Inside the controller you set some instance-variables (e.g. `@bets`), and these will then be available in the view.

So in controller there would be an `index` method, which has the following code

```
def index
  @bets = Bet.find(:all)
end
```

and inside your view you just render them.

So the answer of @dmarkow is entirely correct, but maybe still a bit too deep for you.

Anyway: i would suggest picking a good book, like [Agile Web Development With Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails), which is very good to get started.

[EDIT: added after viewing the paste]

Not sure, but you seem to be missing a `show` method. And if I understand correctly, inside the `show` of a single bet, you want to list all bets of single user? Actually, to be more REST, that would be the user show view, or a user-scoped bets-view, or the standard bets-view. It is common practice that if a user visits a index page, he only gets to see his own items (in this case `bets` --and not all existing bets: only an admin would see those).

So while it is unlike REST to show a list of bets inside the bets show-view, it is definitely possible.

Also i saw that inside your view, you try to find all bets of the user: this is generally code you would place inside the controller instead. You want to keep code in your view to a minimum.
SO inside your `bets_controller.rb` I would add

```
def show
  @bets = @user.bets.order("twitter_tstamp DESC")
end
```

and inside your view you would use `@bets.each` instead. For the rest I object to the use of a single letter `w` (which makes no sense to me --but maybe it does for you); for a `bet` i would suggest `b`, but with Rubymine you have no longer any excuse to save on your variable-names: it only makes your code terribly hard to read later on.

What doesn't work in the view you show? On which line do you get an error?

Comment: First off, thanks for the response. I am very new to web app development and it can get pretty intimidating! I've always had the whole learn-as-you-do mentality, so I've gotten knee-deep into this stuff and now I guess I've hit a roadblock!

I did use scaffolding, which has given me a somewhat clear picture of how things are tied together. I will try what you mentioned and come back if I run into any issues.

Thanks again, appreciate it.

Comment: I created the method (I called it all_bets) in my controller. How could I call or reference this method from my view in haml? I'm essentially trying to retrieve all the bets, and then only display a few based on the username. I keep getting a "We're sorry, but something went wrong." error, which is frustrating because I don't know *why* it went wrong.

Comment: You are not supposed to call methods defined in a controller from your view. You should have an `index` method, with a corresponding `index.html.haml` view. Inside your `index` method you could call the `all_bets`. If you show your complete controller and view code, i could show what is wrong.

Comment: I've attached relevant sections of the code here: http://pastebin.com/rJWMntL0 . index.html.haml is being used for other purposes; the haml file I'm using for displaying bets is in show.html.haml. The very bottom of the code is what I've commented out (based on the answers in this post).

Comment: You seem to be missing the `show` method in the controller, but i can see no obvious error (while rails works without it, it is good practice to define it if used). I have added some general remarks to my answer. Are you still getting an error?

Comment: I've added more details to my question which I was not able to add to this comment due to the word limit.

Comment: `We're sorry, but something went wrong` ? normally in development mode you see the exception raised. Please check your logfile for the precise error. Now the view-code you showed: it is normal since `@bets` and `bet` is `nil`, `bet.all` will raise an exception. Seems weird that if you can write the top-part of the view, you struggle with such basic principles. I repeat myself: do you have a `show` method? If yes, add your code to find all bets there, and store the found data in an instance variable (they start with `@`). Then use that variable in the view.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller's method, if you wanted to find bets based on a user id, you could do this:

```
@bets = Bet.where("user_id = ?", 1)
```

Then in your view, this will iterate through the bets:

```
- for bet in @bets
  = bet.text
  -# insert anything else you'd want to output
```

Comment: or `Bet.all(:conditions => {:user_id => 1})` for Rails 2.x. And just to be clean: `Bet.where(:user_id => 1)`

Comment: I created an "all_bets" method in my BetController:
(def all_bets
    @bets = Bet.where(:user_id => 1)
end) that I'm then calling as you had said, but I'm getting an error now ("We're sorry, but something went wrong."). Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

When you say `Bet.find(:all)` you're getting an iterator back and `#{}` calls `.to_s` on its content to produce a string. So, something like this:

```
"Blah blah #{Bet.find(:all)} mumble"
```

is pretty much like this:

```
"Blah blah " + Bet.find(:all).to_s + " mumble"
```

And so you get a pile of memory addresses and nonsense.

See dmarkow's answer for a better idea of what you should be doing but if you're using Rails 2 then you'll want

```
@bets = Bet.find(:all, :conditions => [ 'user_id = ?', 1])
```

as, AFAIK, `.where` was added in Rails 3.